# Distribute air apps without recompiling

Tags: android, windows, actionscript-3, bitmap, air

I'm developing an air image viewing application for Windows and Android that will allow some special users to import bitmaps to it. The user can click on a button, browse to a bitmap stored locally and then the app saves the image to the documentsDirectory.

Later on, other users (let's call then common users) will get this already compiled app and view the images imported by the special users.

My question is how can I make the app save the images within it without recompiling it?

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option I can think of, is to make a web server to store and load the images by those users. That's because the images will be stored in the documents or cache directory of the **device** which means that there is no automatic way to bring them to other devices.

You need a web server that the images will be uploaded and saved, and later on retrieved by other clients. It's called centralized assets system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Andrey Popov! So the app would store the images in a web server instead of the local storage system, isn't it? I'll find a way to accomplish this!

Comment: There are a lot of online services for that, if you can't develop it yourself (which again is not that hard task). Think about the devices as a chalkboard that you give to a person - he can write something, but it won't go directly to other people's boards - you must copy it :) Anyways - great I could help. Good luck with the server thing!